# End a block on the last page in xsl-fo

Tags: xsl-fo

So, I've got a set of charges I want to show up on a report. I've got them in the right place and everything using flow maps, but I need the list of charges to finish on the last page, rather than necessarily starting on the first. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean **page-position="last"** ?

```
<fo:conditional-page-master-reference
master-reference="lastpage"
page-position="last" > ....all staff...
```

Comment: I don't want it to appear only on the last page. I just want it so that it ends on the last page, e.g., if there's 7 charges (and 5 fit per page), it would start on the second to last page, print 5, then print 2 on the last page.